# Align leged text in figure caption Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I cannot choose to align the legend text of a figure in sphinx.

```
.. figure:: check_validity.png
   :align: center

   ..

   Left: the source layer

   Right: in blue the valid layer, in green the invalid layer and in red the error
   layer
```

This the result:

[image]

But I would like to have both caption aligned left. Is this possible without using tables?

Comment: Do you want to center align the image relative to the page? For the text, do you want to left align it relative to the page or the image?

Comment: I would like to align the text left relative to the image.. do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is very kludgy, requiring custom CSS to account for each image's width.

Here's the HTML that Sphinx generates for me:

```
<div class="figure align-center">
    <img src="check_validity.png" />
    <div class="legend">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Another sentence</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Depending on your theme, you would need to:

1. get the width of the image (WI)
2. get the width of the content area (WCA), which might be impossible if it is a fluid, variable width area
3. calculate the left margin: LM = (WCA - WI)/2
4. apply LM as the left margin to the paragraph block with a CSS selector

It's far easier to just use tables. Welcome to the 1990s!

Here's the reST markup:

```
.. rst-class:: table-center

+--------------------------------+
| .. figure:: check_validity.png |
|                                |
|   ..                           |
|                                |
|   Left: the source layer       |
|                                |
|   Right: in blue the valid     |
|   layer, in green the invalid  |
|   layer and in red the error   |
|   layer                        |
+--------------------------------+
```

And you will need to add a custom style to your CSS file:

```
table.table-center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: ok I see that there are not easy way to do that. I have to turn to css custom stylesheet. Thanks!